# How to retrieve an object from Parse.com after saving it

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm creating an application for Phonegap using Backbone framework and Parse.com as backend service. I create an object with Parse.com (corresponding to Backbone models).
This object has a **saveDraftToP()** method that calls the Parse.com function save().
After this method is called from a view, I'd like to retrieve the updated object.
To do so I'm binding the 'change' event to the model but the Parse assigned ID is undefined.
Here is the code of the model:

```
  var Match = Parse.Object.extend("Match", {
  states: {'DRAFT': 0, 'RUNNING': 1, 'ENDED': 2},
  saveDraftToP: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.save({
      user: Parse.User.current(),
      ACL: new Parse.ACL(Parse.User.current()),
      state: self.states.DRAFT
    }, {
      success: function (result) {
        self = result;
      },
      error: function (e) {

      }
    });
  }
});`
```

And here is the code for the view:

```
       var vmNuovaPartita = Parse.View.extend({
            template: Handlebars.compile(template),
            model: new Match(),
            collection: new HintCollection(),
            initialize: function () {
                this.bind("change:model", console.log(this.model.id) , this);
            },

            render: function (eventName) {
                var match = this.model.toJSON();
                $(this.el).html(this.template(match));
                return this;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you have a save function wrapped in another save-like function. :-)

Say you have something like `myMatch` which is an object.

Through your UI, a button click saves the object data. You can just use `myMatch.save({attr:val, ...})` straight out of the box. Backbone (and Parse) by default are optimistic. That means, you it will set the values of the model with the expectation that persisting to the server will succeed.

Thus, you don't need to retrieve anything extra. You already have the model in it's most current state.

To have a model view that responds to these changes, I'd design the view a little differently.

```
var vmNuovaPartita = Parse.View.extend({
        template: Handlebars.compile(template),
        initialize: function () {
            this.model.on('change', this.render);
        },
        render: function (eventName) {
            var match = this.model.toJSON();
            $(this.el).html(this.template(match));
            return this;
        }
    });

var myView = new vmNuovaPartita({
    model: myModel
});
```

I'd initialize the model outside of the view, then pass it in as an option when you generate a new view. When you pass a model in as an option, it's special and will be attached directly to the view ... view.model which you can refer inside your view code as this.model

In the init we place a listener on the model for change events, then fire off a rerender of the view. Or a nicer way to go about this sort of thing is to throw in the newer Backbone Events with the `.listenTo()` method.